# I have two images that I want to display in a single row next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am unable to display in one row. I will be looping the images dynamically. So if there are 4 to 5 images, then it should come in one row. But if there are more than 5 images or you can say 9, then it should come in next rows. In the below code, I am using HTML and CSS but unable to get in same row.

```css
#umar {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>

<div id="umar">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you use something like the grid system in Boostrap rather than trying to build your own responsive template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use float:left in card class like this:-

```
 .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      float:left;
      width: 20%; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Since I am using same designs, why the two divs are not of same height? How can I make the two same. I think, this is because of using different pictures of different properties. How can I remedy this? Thanking you!

Comment: use `max-height` to set a maximum height of a div

Comment: By using max-height in class "card", images are getting overlapped.

Comment: what value did you give to `max-height` on card class? Height will depend on your image height. can't check because you have relative url in your code

Comment: max-height: 100px;

Comment: max-height wont overlap. it may cut the images. might be someother property giving this issue

Comment: Could you please give a rough sketch. What should I use to avoid two different height of same div, Thanks.

Comment: it might be because of different image size. either use same size images or use max-height and height property to make it equal.

Comment: I really appriciate your effort. Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `float:left` for card class:

```
.card{
  float:left
}
```

and also use media query for div width of the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

I would add `display: flex` for your container `#umar`. Also you can optionally set CSS property `align-items` for vertical positioning.

```css
#umar {
  display: flex; /* new */
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>

<div id="umar">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```